# Recommend me a file sharing protocol

Tags: ubuntu, file-sharing

I'm looking for a file sharing protocol that.

- has client software for ubuntu and mac os x
- has server software for ubuntu.
- lets me mount encrypted file partitions using [pam_mount](http://pam-mount.sourceforge.net/). (or something similar)
- allows random access

What doesn't work

#### FTP

There's no random read access.

#### Samba

Doesn't allow me to mount my encrypted partitions with pam_mount, because the password isn't sent in clear. (And encrypting the volume with the stored hash is pretty insecure because the hash is weak.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use SFTP. I initially thought it wouldn't allow random read/write access, but it does.

Answer (score 2):

Plaintext password doesn't have to be a requirement. If the file server runs SSH, script a `ssh host mount /dev/encrypted_disk ...` just before accessing the filesystem. (If you use `pam_mount` on your local system too -- add a `pam_exec`.)

Comment: That's a possibility I'm considering. Given that fact that it's also going to act as a backup disk it would be nice if that worked without any user intervention though. So SSH'ing to the server is suboptimal.

Comment: You can SSH without user intervention - it requires you to use keys instead of passwords

Comment: @Broam: Which it turn makes it impossible to decrypt the partition, because the password is used as the key for it.

Comment: @Georg: Not necessarily. You use keys for SSH authentication, but then pass the PAM password to a program being ran over SSH. This could be achieved using [`pam_ssh.so`](http://pam-ssh.sf.net/) to unlock the SSH keys, and `pam_exec.so expose_authtok ssh remotehost mount blahblah` to mount the remote filesystem. (`expose_authtok` will make `pam_exec.so` give your login password to `ssh` through stdin, to be consumed by remote `mount`. It's a relatively new addition to Linux-PAM, though.)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this is what happens: *You log in and the computer automatically sshs to the server.* That means, I actually don't need to use keys, because this works only on login (using gdm, ssh, ...) Basically, this is mount-on-login. Did I understand that correctly? (I'm using pam_mount at the moment to mount the encrypted partitions on the server on SSH login anyway, but that works only for password-logins obviously.)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at NFS.

Comment: I did. Is there a simple way of configuring it without going crazy?

Comment: I just read a little bit about how authentication works with NFS. Apparently one has to use a separate kerberos server. Doesn't this mean that pam_mount won't work because the password is never sent to the file server?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use either SMB or NFS with an [SSH tunnel](http://www.google.com/search?q=ssh+tunnel).

Watch out with NFS though. I've had a lot of problems with it on OSX using large files. The OSX client will try to cache a 4GB file in memory then the OS runs out of mememory and starts paging like mad and thrashes the HDD. The entire computer becomes unresponsive.